# Why aren't the TLD registries the TLS CAs?

Tags: tls, certificate-authority

Here's one thing I don't understand - why is it possible for a Chinese organization to forge an SSL certificate for an American website and the other way round? What led to a design decision of creating general CAs instead of forcing the TLD registries to verify identity of the domain owners, only allowing - for example - .com TLD registry to sign .com certificates?

Answer (score 4):

simply because CA's predate TLD Registrars. The whole Idea of Certificates have there origins in the [DAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_Access_Protocol) times (Directory Access Protocol), When the Idea was more along the lines of Central Directories giving Authority to specific users from certificates. (I am paraphrasing here)

For historical reference. the first DNS (BIND) is from 1984. Many years after.